# Perl scripting error : Can't load for module DBI

Tags: perl

Any idea why I'm getting this error?
Is it that I'm not able to run 32 bit Perl on 64 bit installed version?

> [eambtchd@nykdsr000000900:~/stage4/nyfeamld/EAMBatch/apps/default_ol/loader/bin$> perl rmOldRecord.pl
>           Can't load '/home/eambtchd/stage4/nyfeamld/EAMBatch/site_perl/5.8.0/i686-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/DBI.so' for module DBI: 
>       /home/eambtchd/stage4/nyfeamld/EAMBatch/site_perl/5.8.0/i686-linux-thread-multi/auto/DBI/DBI.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32 at /home/eambtchd/utils/perl-5.8.0/lib/5.8.0/i686-linux-thread-multi/DynaLoader.pm line 229.
>            at /home/eambtchd/stage4/nyfeamld/EAMBatch/site_perl/5.8.0/i686-linux-thread-multi/DBI.pm line 254
>           BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/eambtchd/stage4/nyfeamld/EAMBatch/site_perl/5.8.0/i686-linux-thread-multi/DBI.pm line 254.
>           Compilation failed in require at rmOldRecord.pl line 6.
>           BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at rmOldRecord.pl line 6.

Answer (score 6):

You're trying to load an install of DBI that was compiled/installed with a different and incompatible build of Perl.

The directory structure is organised to explicitly avoid this problem! Note the name `i686-linux-thread-multi`? That's not the arch of the Perl you're using, so it should NEVER look in there. Whatever you did to make it look there is very wrong.

Undo that, then install DBI if necessary.