# Issue while installing DBI Perl module in Solaris 11

Tags: perl, solaris

I am trying to install Perl DBI module on Solaris 11 manually using Make install:

You can verify the steps mentioned below.

```
/usr/perl5/5.12/ModulesTars/DBI-1.643# make test
"/usr/bin/perl" -MExtUtils::Command::MM -e 'cp_nonempty' 
-- DBI.bs blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBI.bs 644
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 "/usr/bin/perl" "-Iblib/lib" "-Iblib/arch" test.pl
test.pl
DBI test application $Revision$
Can't load '/usr/perl5/5.12/ModulesTars/DBI-1.643/blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBI.so' 
for module DBI: ld.so.1: perl:
fatal: /usr/perl5/5.12/ModulesTars/DBI-1.643/blib/arch/auto/DBI/DBI.so: 
wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 at
/usr/perl5/5.12/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/DynaLoader.pm line 200.

at /usr/perl5/5.12/ModulesTars/DBI-1.643/blib/lib/DBI.pm line 284
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 
/usr/perl5/5.12/ModulesTars/DBI-1.643/blib/lib/DBI.pm line 284.
Compilation failed in require at test.pl line 23.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 23.
*** Error code 2
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `test_dynamic'
/usr/perl5/5.12/ModulesTars/DBI-1.643#
```

Getting above error while running make test command. Please help to find the resolution.

Comment: *"wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64"* Have you multiple perl binaries installed? It looks like it is trying to run the tests with `/usr/bin/perl`. What version of perl is that?

Comment: See also [Perl scripting error : Can't load for module DBI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16956124/2173773) and [Swig Perl: wrong ELF class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51382757/2173773)

Comment: Perl Version is 5.12.        @INC:
            /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.12/sun4-solaris-64int
            /usr/perl5/site_perl/5.12
            /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12/sun4-solaris-64int
            /usr/perl5/vendor_perl/5.12
            /usr/perl5/5.12/lib/sun4-solaris-64int
            /usr/perl5/5.12/lib

Comment: What is the output of `which perl`? and `perl -V`?

Comment: its just a link to actual perl binary version 5.12

-bash-4.4$ ls -lrt /usr/bin/perl
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     sys           22 Dec 10  2018 /usr/bin/perl -> ../perl5/5.12/bin/perl
-bash-4.4$ pwd
/usr/bin

-bash-4.4$ perl -v

This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 5 (v5.12.5) built for sun4-solaris-64int
(with 7 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Comment: ```
:~$ which perl
/bin/perl
```
:~$ cd /bin
:/bin$ ls -lrt | grep -w perl
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     sys           22 Dec 10  2018 perl -> ../perl5/5.12/bin/perl

Comment: Can you try rebuild DBI with that version of perl given explicitly: `/usr/perl5/5.12/bin/perl Makefile.PL; make; make test` ?

Comment: I got the same error with this version of perl explicitly. /usr/perl5/5.12/bin/perl Makefile.PL; make; make test

Answer (score 1):

Per Oracle's [Solaris 11 Perl 5 documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28996/nsov-8.html):

> Perl 5 includes a dynamically loadable module framework, which allows the addition of new capabilities for specific tasks. Many modules are freely available from the Comprehensive Perl Archive Network (CPAN) at http://www.cpan.org. If you wish to build and install add-on modules from CPAN using gcc, you can do so using the `/usr/perl5/5.8.4/bin/perlgcc` or the `/usr/perl5/5.12/bin/perlgcc` script. See the `perlgcc(1)` man page with the 5.8.4 distribution for details.

**Offtopic:**

Given your comment

> This is perl 5, version 12, subversion 5 (v5.12.5) built for sun4-solaris-64int (with 7 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

Are you really installing user-compiled modules as root into the system's Perl installation?  Since you have "7 registered patches", it seems that this is a system under an Oracle support contract.  Installing user-compiled modules as root into the system Perl installation risks your system's stability and likely violates your support contract.