# Issue while installing DBI Perl module via CPAN prompt on Solaris 11

Tags: perl, solaris

I am getting  error "`sh: cc: not found`" when I try to install `DBI` module from CPAN prompt.  Is there any way to resolve this? I have already installed `gcc` compiler from gnu site.

```
        $ which gcc
        /bin/gcc
        $
```

and environment variable is already set like this `cc=gcc`

But, still I got this error:

```
cc -c    -I/usr/gnu/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DPERL_USE_SAFE_PUTENV -xO3    -DVERSION=\"1.643\"  -DXS_VERSION=\"1.643\" -KPIC "-I/usr/perl5/5.12/lib/sun4-solaris-64int/CORE"  -DDBI_NO_THREADS Perl.c
sh: cc: not found
*** Error code 127
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `Perl.o'
Current working directory /root/.cpan/build/DBI-1.643-2
  TIMB/DBI-1.643.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- NOT OK
Failed during this command:
 TIMB/DBI-1.643.tar.gz                        : make NO
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a (symbolic) link `cc` in the `$PATH` to `/bin/gcc` as a workaround?

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421790/issue-while-installing-dbi-perl-module-in-solaris-11)?  You don't appear to be even trying to use the `perlgcc` scripts as [the Oracle documentation for compiling modules for Perl 5 with gcc on Solaris 11 states](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26502_01/html/E28996/nsov-8.html)

Comment: The environment variable should be `CC`, not `cc`. Case matters.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid any binary incompatibilities, Perl expects all C code to be compiled with the same compiler as was used to build Perl itself. It looks like you're using the standard Solaris installation of Perl. That will have been built with the Solaris C compiler, not with `gcc` (you can check by running `perl -V:cc`).

So you're going to need the Solaris C compiler installed in order to install any CPAN modules that require C code to be compiled.

It's been years (decades probably) since I used Solaris. Is there no standardised package repository that you can use to install extra packages - something like RedHat's `rpm`?

Comment: Can anyone share steps to download and install c compiler for Solaris 11

Comment: @AshishSahoo: I would expect that's a question for a Solaris group.